# Different Eigenvectors, same Basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over the field $K$. Let $A,B$ be linear maps of $V$ into itself, and assume that $AB=BA$. Assume that there exists a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, and a basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $B$. Show that there exists a basis all of whose lelements are eigenvectors of both A and B(i.e A and B can be simultaneously diagonalized). ***Linear Algebra, Serge Lang.***

As $AB=BA$

$Av=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i$, where $v_i$ and $v=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}v_i$ is a basis of $V$.

If $w\in V$, then $ABw=BAw=B\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iw_i=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iBw$

So the eigenspace of $B$ and  the Eigenspace of A are the same according to the last procedure.

So it means we can talk about the same basis:
$Av=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iv_i$, $Bv=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}b_iv_i$

Question:

Is my proof right, complete?

Is the following deduction true?

> If $w\in V$, then $ABw=BAw=B\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iw_i=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iBw$
>
> So the eigenspace of $B$ and  the Eigenspace of A are the same according to the last procedure.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Not even close. You start with “As $AB=BA$”, but what follows as nothing to do with $B$. Then, you mention $Av$ without saying what $v$ is.

Then you write$$BAw=B\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iw_i=\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n}a_iBw.$$ Why? Where does the last equality come from?

Concerning the sentence “So the eigenspace of $B$ and symmetrically the Eigenspace of $A$ are the same.”, I don't even know what it means.

Comment: Is it clearer after my last edit?

Comment: @PedroGomes The last sentence that I mentioned became a little more clear, but you seem to believe that $A$ and $B$ have a single eigenspace. My other remarks were not affected by your edition.

Comment: Cannot we infer from the fact that $AB=BA$ that the matrices have the same eigenspace? Thinking in another Vector Space  $V$, it is true if $Av=\lambda v$ that $ABv=BAv=B\lambda v=\lambda B v$, and we have the same for $Bv=\alpha v$. Which lead me to conclude that thre Eigenspace is the same. This was presented to me in the last exercise. Perhaps this one differs but I am not seeing how.

Comment: @PedroGomes You can conclude that they have the same *eigenspaces*, not the same *eigenspace*. There's more than one, in general.